# binding.pry being skipped in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binding, pry

`binding.pry` is not catching for me in some situations.

For instance, when I run this code using `ruby programtorun.rb` in the terminal, it doesn't open up a Pry session.

```
require 'pry'

class Foo
  def bar
    boo = true
    binding.pry
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar
```

I tried reinstalling Pry but the problem persisted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `binding.pry` stops on the next line to be executed in your program.  Your next line is non-existent.  `binding.pry` is literally the last thing you call before your script ends.

Changing

```
class Foo
  def bar
    boo = true
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

to

```
class Foo
  def bar
    binding.pry
    boo = true
  end
end
```

caused it to stop for me at `boo=true`.